# Prove $\tan:(-\pi/2,\pi/2) \to \mathbb{R}$ can be extended to a homeomorphism $\overline{\tan}:[-\pi/2,\pi/2] \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $\overline{\mathbb{R}} = \{-\infty\} \cup \mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$ with the topology given by the subbase composed by the rays $[-\infty,a)=\{-\infty\}\cup\{x;x<a\}$ and $(b,\infty]=\{x;x>b\} \cup \{\infty\}$, where $a,b$ vary in $\mathbb{R}$.

Prove the homeomorphism $\tan:(-\pi/2,\pi/2) \to \mathbb{R}$ can be extended to a homeomorphism $\overline{\tan}:[-\pi/2,\pi/2] \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$.

I'm kinda lost on what do I need to do here, so I'd appreciate any guidance. I believe what is need to be done here is prove that $\overline{\tan}$ is an homeomorphism.

Here is my "attempt" on proving continuity of $\overline{\tan}$: Let $A \subseteq \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ an open set. Then $A = \bigcup_{\lambda \in \Lambda} A_{\lambda}$, where each $A_{\lambda}$ is of the form $[-\infty,a), (a,b)$ or $(b,\infty]$.

$\overline{\tan}^{-1}(A) = \overline{\tan}^{-1}\left(\bigcup_{\lambda \in \Lambda} A_{\lambda}\right)=\bigcup_{\lambda \in \Lambda} \overline{\tan}^{-1}(A_{\lambda})$

Now I need to show each $\overline{\tan}^{-1}(A_{\lambda})$ is open on $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, right? I'm not quite sure how to do that.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show that

- $\overline\tan^{-1}\big[(a,b)\big]=\left(\tan^{-1}a,\tan^{-1}b\right)$,
- $\overline\tan^{-1}\big[[-\infty,a)\big]=\left[-\frac{\pi}2,\tan^{-1}a\right)$, and
- $\overline\tan^{-1}\big[(b,\infty]\big]=\left(\tan^{-1}b,\frac{\pi}2\right]$.

That will show that $\tan$ is continuous. Showing that it is also open is very similar.

Comment: Thank you very much. I believe you meant that will show that $\overline{\tan}$ is continuous, right?

Comment: @user1618: You’re welcome, and yes, I most certainly did; thanks for catching that.